# Allow sheet to both automatically add author and date row last edited and sort columns

Tags: excel, vba

I need an Excel VB script that will allow sheet to automatically list in column `I` the name of the author editing the corresponding row, add the date in which the row was last edited in column `J`, then sort column `D` ascending and sort column `E` descending. I got the first part done below but don't know how to add the ascending and descending? any ideas...

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' declare constants and variables
    Const owner_col As String = "I"
    Const date_col As String = "J"
    Dim row As Double
    Dim owner_addr As Range
    Dim date_addr As Range

    ' initialise
    row = Target.row
    Set owner_addr = Range(owner_col & row)
    Set date_addr = Range(date_col & row)

    ' check that the update is not to the fields you want to update to avoid infinite loop
    If Target.Address <> owner_addr.Address And Target.Address <> date_addr.Address Then
        ' set values
        owner_addr.Value = Environ("username")
        date_addr.Value = Now()
    End If

   ' free up the memory
   Set owner_addr = Nothing
   Set date_addr = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Use [Range.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort) where the `Range` is the worksheet area where your data is. Use `Key1`, `key2`, `Order1`, `Order2` to have the range sort based on `D` and `E` and sort ascending & descending as required.

Comment: "auto-sort" can be a bit annoying/surprising though?  You want to review what you just wrote but then it's "gone"...